# SQL Server db_owner

Tags: sql-server, security, owner

in my SQL2008 I have a user which is in the "db_datareader", "db_datawriter" and "db_ddladmin" DB roles, however when he tries to modify a table with SSMS he receives a message saying:

*You are not logged in as the database owner or system administrator. You might not be able to save changes to tables that you do not own.*

Of course, I would like to avoid such message, but until now I did find the way...
Therefore, I try to modify the user by adding him to the "db_owner" role, and of course I do not have the message above.

My question is:

- Is it possible to keep the user in the "db_owner" role, but deny some actions like alter user or ? I try "alter any user" securable on DB level, but it does not work...

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user is part of `db_ddladmin` it shouldn't be a problem.  This is just a [warning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164237.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Members of the [db_ddladmin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190667(SQL.90).aspx) fixed database role can run any Data Definition Language (DDL) command in a database. It is probably just a warning from SSMS, try it out create a user and try to alter some tables

Answer (score 1):

My understanding has always been that any user with db_owner rights can do **anything** to a database, up to and including dropping it. Certainly, this was true through SQL 2005.  I've heard nothing to imply that this has changed with SQL 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Those are indeed warnings, and I don't see any way to disable that type of warning in SSMS.

In 2008R2 the behavior I'm seeing is users with "db_datareader", "db_datawriter" and "db_ddladmin" still need to be granted view definition to be able to make edits in SSMS by right-clicking and selecting design.  If you haven't granted view definition, then the design view will open (with warnings) read-only.

See:  [MSFT Connect Bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/467582/db-ddladmin-role-doesnt-allow-use-of-design-functions-in-ssms?wa=wsignin1.0)

To me it seems more discoverable to assign view definition permissions to your ddladmin users through a role, rather than doing it for specific user accounts as stated in the workaround on Connect.  This will add a db_definitionviewer database role:

```
USE <DB Name>;
CREATE ROLE db_definitionviewer;
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION TO db_definitionviewer;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_definitionviewer', '<DOMAIN\group> | <DOMAIN\User>';
```